# Call Html.RenderAction from inside HTML string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application that uses database to store pages (HTML), galleries, forms etc... I want to provide users a functionality to call other controller from inside pages.

Simplified problem is how to call render action from database acquired string. Just for example I would like that string contains `@Html.RenderAction("Show", "Gallery", new {id=5})`

Another option I have to parse string inside a controller and render all sub calls to string before rendering this HTML.

EDIT:
The database would return something like code bellow, service layer can substitute {$gallery$} with `@Html.RenderAction("Show", "Gallery", {id=5})`

```
<div class="text">
<h1> title </h1>
<p> this is some random text {$gallery$} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `Simplified problem is how to call render action from database acquired string.` -- Does this mean that you want to use the action and controller name dynamically in `@Html.RenderAction` ?

Comment: Yes, I will have a js interface so user can add gallery inside HTML element. Lets say plugin to tinyMCE, like inserting image you can insert gallery, but gallery calls specific gallery controller with id. If I understood the question

Answer (score 0):

From your statement

> Simplified problem is how to call render action from database acquired
>   string.

I get that you want to call an action using dynamically provided `action-name` and `controller`. If this what you want you could get it using

**ViewModel**

```
 public class MyViewModel{

   public string Action {get;set;}

   public string ControllerName {get;set;}

 }
```

**Controller**

```
  public class MyController : Controller{

       public ActionResult MyView(){

         return View(new MyViewModel 
                   { Action ="MyPartialView" , ControllerName = "my"});
       }

       public ActionResult MyPartialView(){
         return PartialView();
       }
  }
```

**View**

```
 @model MyView

  ....render stuff for the view

@{
   Html.RenderAction(Model.Action,Model.ControllerName);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I've edited the question to better explain the problem.